# Joining 3 tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables: **Questions**, **Answers** & **Ratings**

I want to join the `answers` table with `questions` table where `questions.id = answers.question_id`  and `ratings` table to `answers` table where `answers.id = ratings.answer_id`

But it returns `null`

```
 $allQuestionWithAnswerAndRating = DB::table('questions')->orderBy('questions.id','desc' )
    ->join( 'answers', 'questions.id' , '=' , 'answers.question_id' )
    ->where('answers.user_id', '=' ,Auth::user()->id )
    ->join( 'ratings', 'answers.id' , '=' , 'ratings.answer_id')
    ->select( 'questions.id as id' , 'questions.body as question' , 'answers.body as answer' ,'answers.user_id as user_id')
    ->get();
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `->leftJoin` instead. Maybe some of your data results aren't quite what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the advanced join statements section of the [eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#joins).

> You may also specify more advanced join clauses. To get started, pass
> a Closure as the second argument into the join method. The Closure
> will receive a JoinClause object which allows you to specify
> constraints on the join clause
>
> ....
>
> If you would like to use a "where" style clause on your joins, you may
> use the where and orWhere methods on a join. Instead of comparing two
> columns, these methods will compare the column against a value:

For your statement that would look something like this:

```
DB::table('questions')
    ->join( 'answers', function($join) {
        $join->on('questions.id' , '=' , 'answers.question_id')
             ->where('answers.user_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id);
    })->join( 'ratings', 'answers.id' , '=' , 'ratings.answer_id')
    ->select(
        'questions.id as id', 
        'questions.body as question', 
        'answers.body as answer',
        'answers.user_id as user_id'
    )->get();
```